# Accepting License Installing PyQT5 OSX arm64

Tags: pyqt5, pandasgui

I'm trying to install PandasGUI, which has PyQT5 as a dependency.  I added `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.5_1/bin` to my `.zshrc`.  When I run `pip3 --no-cache-dir --verbose install git+https://github.com/adamerose/pandasgui.git` or `pip3 --no-cache-dir --verbose install pandasgui`,

```
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
  This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.7 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.9.13 on darwin.

  Type 'L' to view the license.
  Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
  Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.
```

and typing `'yes'`, `yes`, or `L`/`'L'` doesn't do anything (yes I push enter afterwards).  I even tried `yes | pip3 --no-cache-dir --verbose install pandasgui` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Having the same problem. For me it's resulting in an memory error.

Comment: also having a problem on MacOS Ventura - I have a conda environment where I: 1. installed Xcode tools (scrub - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a) 2. have installed PyQT 15.5 and 3. have also upgraded pip and pyqt... however, the installation of pandasgui just hangs at Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) (licence problem?)